# Rust macro repetition with plus

Tags: rust

How can the `+` operator be used as a repetition separator?

```
fn dot(self, rhs: Self) -> S {
    $(self.$s * rhs.$s)++
}
```

`$s` will be `x`, `y`, `z`, so I would like the macro to exapnd to `self.x * rhs.x + self.y * rhs.y + self.z * rhs.z`. If I write `$(self.$s * rhs.$s)-+`, then it works and expands to subtractions, but I need additions, is it possible to escape the `+` token?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, [this isn't directly possible](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18700) (as of rustc 1.41). The workaround mentioned at that issue is to put the plus before every item in the repetition and have a separate macro that strips off the extra plus at the front.

```
macro_rules! strip_plus {
    (+ $($rest: tt)*) => {
        $($rest)*
    }
}
```

It's used like this:

```
macro_rules! sum_all {
    ($($items: tt)+) => {
        strip_plus!($(+ $items)+)
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(sum_all!(1 2 3 4 5), 15);
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d4dc6ba881075708aeafed1d5cbcfa85)

Comment: This isn't possible in trait bounds context. You can't call a macro there.